# Find leading order matched asymptotic expansion for $\epsilon y'' + y y' - y = 0; y(0) = -1, y(1) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, perturbation-theory

**My attempt:**

The outer problem for leading order term: $$y_0 y_0' - y_0 = 0$$
This has solution: $y_0(x) = 0$ or $y_0(x) = x + c$.

I notice that $y(x) < 0$ on this interval, so I assume the boundary layer is at $x = 1$. So the outer solution is: $$y_0(x) = x - 1$$
Note that this alone solves the differential equation.

I approached the inner problem with the scaling: $ z = \frac{1 -x}{\epsilon}$. This leads to: $$ y_0''(z) - y_0(z) y_0'(z) = 0 $$
The solution for this is either $y_0(z) = C$ or, 
$$ y_0(z) = \sqrt{2} C \tan\left({\frac{(z+D)C}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)$$
With the B.C. $y_0(z = 0) = 0$, then $D = \frac{\sqrt{2} n \pi}{C}$, and the solution becomes:
$$ y_0(z) = \sqrt{2} C \tan\left({\frac{zC+\sqrt{2}n\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)$$
Classical matching:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} y_0(x) = \lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} y_0(z) $$
Or,
$$ 0 = \sqrt{2} C \tan\left({\frac{\infty \cdot C+\sqrt{2}n\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)$$
Thus, it requires $C = n = 0$.
This means the outer solution is the leading approximate solution for this problem.

**My question:** I don't think this is correct, but I am not sure how else to approach this. ( I am not supposed to use other matching methods).

Comment: Same ODE, different boundary conditions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1286926/115115

Comment: Check again the inner equation, the solution should be in the hyperbolical tangent, where then also the limit to infinity makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These particular boundary values are a bit special. You didn't make any mistakes in your analysis, as far as I can see. Your conclusion that the outer solution is the leading order approximate solution is also correct. In fact, the outer solution is an *exact* solution to the problem with these boundary conditions (try it, you'll see that $y_0$ solves the original problem exactly). So, for this special choice of boundary conditions, the boundary layer vanishes.